# Would this code cause memory leakage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Would this cause memory leak ?

```
var mc:MovieClip ; //<<<<<<< OUTSIDE LOOP

for ( var i=0 ; i< 1000 ; i++)
{
   mc = new MovieClip() ;
   mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK , onClick) ;
}
```

And what about this ?

```
for ( var i=0 ; i< 1000 ; i++)
{
  var mc:MovieClip ; //<<<<<<< INSIDE LOOP
   mc = new MovieClip() ;
   mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK , onClick) ;
}
```

"removeEventListener" is not used in any of the above code, so I think that both are causing a memory leak.

Comment: Neither are causing a memory leak at this point as you may require all 1000 movieclips to be clickable. It's only when you have done with movieclips and wish to remove them from memory that the event listener issue comes in to play. Ascention's answer is correct but the word 'would' is important.

Comment: Everyone here, I stand corrected. I will never trust the adobe documentation ever again. See my updated answer. My current answer is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 1000 Movieclips will have a reference to you onClick function. Not the other way around.
So if you question is if your 1000 Movieclips will get GCed: They will eventually, if they don't have any other reference.

On the other hand the reference in your movieclips to your onClick function will keep that alive (and the object it might belong to). If those MCs have any other reference that will keep them alive.

The following code:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , function(ev:Event):void{  trace("I am only a poor anonymous function");  }, false, 0, true);
```

Will have your listener function GCed pretty soon, as it doesn't have any strong reference.

setting **useWeakReference** to true can be pretty relevant if your adding an Eventlistener to your stage

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someObjectBelowIntheDisplayList.listenerFunction);
```

The above code will keep the Object with your listener Function alive, even if it has no other reference.

```
someObjectBelowIntheDisplayList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stage.onClick)
```

the above code will not keep your **someObjectBelowIntheDisplayList** alive. It has a reference to the stage, but the stage does not get a reference to **someObjectBelowIntheDisplayList**

Edit: Please try the following code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var mc:MovieClip ; //<<<<<<< OUTSIDE LOOP

function enterframe(ev:Event):void
{
    for ( var i=0 ; i< 1000 ; i++)
    {
       mc = new MovieClip() ;
       mc.onClick = function(ev:Event){};
       // Use one of the following lines, comment out the other one
       //mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK , onClick) ; // no memory leak
       stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mc.onClick); // memory will rise up and up
    }
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);

function onClick(ev:Event):void
{

}
```

This code clearly supports what I am saying: Using mc.addEventListener will **not** get the memory consumption up. It will stay around 20MB on my system.
When using the line with the stage.addEventListener and using mc.onClick as the listener function, memory consumption will rise every frame.

Comment: The test code I have provided above constantly does create 1000 Movieclips on every frame. If there was a memory leak, the memory consumption **has** to grow, as all those objects would not be collected. but they are. By adding the Movieclips as listeners to the stage, there is a memory leak. The reference always is from the dispatcher to the listener, not the other way around. so if there is no reference to the dispatcher anymore, it will be destroyed, no matter how many listeners it might have.

Comment: You're 100% right sir. I stand corrected. I updated my answer with more information. It seems that adobe has added new information since the last time I read the documentation. I also asked for my answer to be marked as incorrect and the credit be given to you.

Comment: What's the point of adding ENTER_FRAME event. Wasn't the loop sufficient  ?

Comment: @Vishwas Gagrani The loop will create 1000 Movieclips, and then nothing more will happen. If there is a Memory leak, those 1000 clips won't be garbage collected, but they also might not GCed because there is no need to, as memory is not growing any further. By using the ENTER_FRAME event and creating more and more movieclips on every frame, I am making sure to exploit the memory leak. If there is one, the memory consumption will grow and grow. If there is none, the GC will collect those movieclips and dispose them, leaving the memory usage on a constant level.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated, Correct Answer**
My original answer was wrong and I sincerely apologize. I will leave all my condescending comments and information intact so that the shame might forever remind me to never trust anything Adobe says again. Current documentation now says:

"If you no longer need an event listener, remove it by calling removeEventListener(), or memory problems could result. Event listeners are not automatically removed from memory because the garbage collector does not remove the listener ***as long as the dispatching object exists*** (unless the useWeakReference parameter is set to true)."

Note that the event listeners ARE garbage collected weather there are weak reference or not, as long as the dispatching object is removed first. So in both of these cases, they will never cause a memory leak. I ask the OP to un-check my answer as correct and give the credit/correct answer + upvotes to @Malyngo.

**Original (wrong)Answer and (mis)Information Follows**
Both would. Binding an event listener creates a strong reference to the original object, and therefore the garbage collector will not clean it up. You need to remove the event listeners explicitly or specify them as weak references, which should be one of the parameters of addEventListener.

**For the people arguing that listeners won't stop other objects from being garbage collected**

http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/

Summary of article:

"Imagine that our player dies, and we want him to be cleaned up. However, the event listener creates a reference from the stage to the player. The stage is the topmost display object and is always accessible. Therefore, when the mark-sweep process runs, this event listener allows the garbage collector to hop from the stage to our player object, even if we’ve cleared all other references and removed it from the display list."

***So there is still at least one scenario where an event listener alone, strongly bound, can prevent an object from being collected***.

Best-practice solution:

1) Remove it from the display list.
2) If it’s a MovieClip, tell it to stop().
3) Remove any event listeners that the object has created.
4) Clear any references in parent objects by setting them to null.

**Update Again**

A memory leak doesn't necessarily mean you will see the applications memory continuously grow. A memory leak can also simply describe memory which is allocated and persists for the life of the application, when it should be recycled. Something like this test code will not be very easily detectable. But make this happen N times over an hour long game and I guarantee you it will show. I had the same situation happen with an encryption algorithm I wrote once. After a while, my app started chugging along at 10 or less frames per second, because the VM had eaten up a ton of memory it wasn't actually using anymore yet it was still managing it.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are the same, as actionscript is based on ecmascript 3 which has no block scope.

edit: Let me be more specific: There is no block scope, but there is function scope in ActionScript.

As with the memory leak, the objects will stay in memory.

Comment: "Has no block scope" is false. If you mean to say that the scope has no bearing on memory allocation and de-allocation that's a different story but to simply say there is no block scope itself is false.

Comment: I would actually say it is true as long as you don't count a function as a block scope and treat it as a scope all of its own. (Which again, technically true).

Comment: I think what wants to say JNissi, is that AS3 use variable hoisting so declaring a variable inside or outside the loop have the same effect ;)