# AS3: Would this cause a memory leak?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, garbage-collection

```
public class MyButton extends Sprite 
{     
   public function MyButton(defaultHandler:Function)     
   {     
      addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, defaultHandler);     
   } 
}
```

//Main class

```
var myButton:MyButton =new MyButton(someFunction);
addChild(myButton)

removeChild(myButton);
myButton = null;
```

IE I am adding an anonymous mouseclick event handler function from inside to my Button class when it is constructed, and not specifically removing it when it is removed from the stage and nulled out.

Would this object be eligible for the garbage collector, wouldn't this cause a memory leak? Or since that the event listener was only referencing an object that itself was removed would it also be removed???

Answer (score 1):

The event listener on the `Button` instance will prevent it from being garbage collected, unless you specifically remove the listener, or signal that the listener will be a weak reference.

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, defaultHandler, false, 0, true);
```

The last argument `true`, is passed for the parameter `useWeakReference`.  From the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29):

> useWeakReference:Boolean (default = false) — Determines whether the
>   reference to the listener is strong or weak. A strong reference (the
>   default) prevents your listener from being garbage-collected. A weak
>   reference does not.

Comment: When setting a listener as weak, the responsibility of removing it is transfered to the garbage collector. You should never trust on GC, since it's mostly random so it could take a while. Weak listeners are for lazy developers who don't take responsibility for cleaning up their own code. The only exception could be an eventlisteners at the stage, but you should always remove the listeners yourself.

Comment: Agreed @MarkKnol, and I always do remove them explicitly.  That being said, that is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: I've found this, which is although a slightly different scenario, but with a similar problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471578/would-this-code-cause-memory-leakage
which has a quote:
"Event listeners are not automatically removed from memory because the garbage collector does not remove the listener **as long as the dispatching object exists** (unless the useWeakReference parameter is set to true)."
- so according to this, IF the object the listener references **no longer exist it should not** persist and should not cause a leak
- can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

While the points in @sberry's answer are totally valid, take a closer look at which objects have references to each other in this scenario.

If the main class is around for the lifetime of the application, **there is no memory leak**:

Main class has a reference to the button class that it instantiated.

Button class has a reference to the main class, from the event handling function.

Main class nulls out its reference to the button.

At this point, there are **no more references to the button**. The button **can** and will be garbage collected.

If the main class truly is around for the lifetime of the app, there is no problem. If somehow the main class goes away, but one of the button objects persists **then** you have a memory leak (the button maintains a reference to main, and main cannot be garbage collected).

PS: I'm not arguing against removing event listeners when or using weak references, I do both of those practices myself as much as possible :)

Comment: Yes this is what I was referring to, that if the object itself no longer exist, then in theory, neither should its event listener.
- can anyone confirm this?

Comment: [Here is an article from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html) that backs up what I'm saying. Garbage collection works in two ways: reference counting (fast), and then "mark and sweep" catches stuff w/circular references (where the count never goes to 0).  In your example, the reference count for the button goes to 0 when you do: `removeChild(myButton); myButton = null;` the button becomes eligible for garbage collection, but there's no guarantee when that will happen.

Comment: Just to clarify and answer the specific question in your comment: when you use `addEventListener()` in the button, the button basically maps that event to a function (defined in your main class in this case). So when the button gets g/c'd, this mapping goes with it and the event listener can be considered to no longer exist. It's still a good practice to remove listeners and/or use weak references when adding them :)